# Finding the point on a bilinear surface closest to a given point: determining if an analytic solution is possible

Tags: optimization, surfaces, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system

Given the surface $$z=f(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}1-x&x\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}b&c\\a&d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1-y\\y\end{bmatrix}$$ defined on $x,y\in[0,1]$, (where $a, b, c$ and $d$ are parameters that equal $f(1, 0), f(0, 0), f(0, 1)$ and $f(1,1)$ respectively), how can I find analytically the point $\mathbf x_c=\left(x_c,y_c,f(x_c,y_c)\right)$ closest to some given point $\mathbf x_b=(x_b,y_b,z_b)$?

Here's what I've tried so far:

If you define a function $$D^2(x,y)=(x_b-x)^2+(y_b-y)^2+(z_b-f(x,y))^2$$ then $\mathbf x_c$ will be the value that minimizes this function -- that is, 
$$\frac{dD^2}{dx}(x_c,y_c)=0\\
\frac{dD^2}{dy}(x_c,y_c)=0$$

This expands to:

$$0=-2(x_b-x_c)-2(z_b-f)\frac{df}{dx}\\
0=-2(y_b-y_c)-2(z_b-f)\frac{df}{dy}$$

**The problem is, when you actually to solve for $x_c$ and $y_c$, the $f$ and $\frac{df}{dk}$ terms expand into such a mess of constants that it becomes nearly impossible to solve by hand.** Wolfram|Alpha also refuses to get anywhere, although I don't know if that's because of the number of terms or because it's actually impossible to solve.

I thought I might be able to solve it using the fact that $\mathbf x_b-\mathbf x_c$ will always be normal to $f$, but that ends up as the same equation:

$$\begin{bmatrix}-\frac{df}{dx}\\ -\frac{df}{dy} \\ 1\end{bmatrix}\text{is a vector normal to }f\\
\mathbf x_b - \mathbf x_c=(\text{some scalar }s)\begin{bmatrix}-\frac{df}{dx}\\ -\frac{df}{dy} \\ 1\end{bmatrix}\\
x_b-x_c=-s\frac{df}{dx}\\
y_b-y_c=-s\frac{df}{dy}\\
z_b-f(x_c,y_c)=s\\
\Rightarrow x_b-x_c=-(z_b-f)\frac{df}{dx}\\
\Rightarrow y_b-y_c=-(z_b-f)\frac{df}{dy}$$

**Does anyone know of a way to simplify the algebra, or a proof that it cannot be solved exactly?** (I've already found some approximations that will work fine for what I need, so I'm not interested in iterative methods; I'm just curious at this point)

Comment: can you say for certain if the surface formed by $(x,y,f(x,y))$ is convex or concave? There might be some hope if yes I think

Comment: The Hessian of $f$ is $\begin{bmatrix}0&b-c-a+d\\b-c-a+d&0\end{bmatrix}$, so it's flat along lines parallel to the $x$ and $y$ axes, and has parameter-dependent curvature along other lines. I'm not sure if this helps or not, since I don't know much about concavity/convexity and how it would help here.

Comment: I'm now facing the exact same problem. Have you been able to come up with solution?

Comment: Nope. Gave up on it a while ago. I'd be interested if you got anywhere, though.

Comment: @a52 Could you please elaborate on the approximation you have found? Thanks.

Comment: @bitpancakes It's been quite a while, so I don't really remember. I think I either divided the surface into flat tris or used some kind of iterative approach (likely Newton's method or something similar). It was for a quick little game, so getting anything exact or O(1) wasn't a priority for me, and I think I may have dropped the bilinear surfaces entirely.